# What are difference in different notations of String array in main method?

Tags: java, arrays, string, program-entry-point

I've used three types of notation while passing argument to `main` method in java.
`public static void main(String[] args)`
`public static void main(String args[])`
`public static void main(String... args)`
Can anyone tell me the difference between above? Someone has used terms packed and non-packed data for explanation of first two, what are they, and is it related to these?
I think first two is somewhat related to coding convention. Am I right?

Comment: When it comes down to it there is no true difference.

Comment: No difference...All start the main thread'

Comment: Downvoters, please comment the reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no actual difference, the variants are due to the different ways you can define an array in java syntax.

- The standard way to define and array

  String[] args
- C/C++ style exist from historical reasons

  String args[]
- Varargs style ([When do you use varargs in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766559/when-do-you-use-varargs-in-java))

  String… args

All will compile to the same bytecode.
I would stick with

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Is there any difference in memory assignment?

Answer (score 0):

First two are same.

Infact all three are same at base. But the third kind is called as `varargs` and has a special purpose which is that it can be used as an optional parameter in methods. For example if you have a method that requires parameters `int x, String... y` then even you call the parameter without passing `String... y` as parameter argument, the code will compile. More information here:  [Methods, Optional Parameters and/or Accepting multiple Data Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929606/methods-optional-parameters-and-or-accepting-multiple-data-types/33929661#33929661)

Also check this: [Java varags method param list vs. array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405673/java-varags-method-param-list-vs-array)